# Prove that $f(x)=\left\vert\,x\,\right\vert - \sin\left(\left\vert\, x\,\right\vert\right)$ is differentiable or discontinuous or has no derivative

Tags: calculus, limits

I have no idea what to do with question number 9, and question number I used $\operatorname{sign}$ for the absolute but I don't know if I used right or wrong, more detail in the picture:
[image]

Comment: Question 9) has nothing to do with the title of your question. In 10) you probably meant $f'(0)$

Comment: @Avitus Sorry, i thought that the title would be very long so i didn't type all in. And yes you are right, i meant f'(0) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition $f(0)=0$, $f(x)=x-\sin(x)$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=-x-\sin(-x)=-x+\sin(x)$ for $x<0$. I used $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$. We want to check whether $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$. We already know that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ (right?). Let us compute the limits

$$f^{'}(0)_{+}:=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h},$$

and

$$f^{'}(0)_{-}:=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^-}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h},$$

checking whether $f^{'}(0)_{+}=f^{'}(0)_{-}=l,$ with $l$ finite. In the first limit $h$ is a small positive increment, while in the second case it is a small negative increment.

Then

$$f^{'}(0)_{+}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{h-\sin(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{+}}1-\frac{\sin(h)}{h}=0,$$

as $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{\sin(h)}{h}=1$ (this is a known result).
The second limit reads

$$f^{'}(0)_{-}=\text{(the increment is negative!)}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{-}}\frac{-h+\sin(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{-}}-1+\frac{\sin(h)}{h}=0.$$

In summary, $f^{'}(0)_{+}=f^{'}(0)_{-}=0$ and $f$ is diff. at $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you, you explained very clearly, i'm newb to calculus , my teacher tough very fast so i mostly self study, but can i use sgn to solve this limit?

Comment: using sgn in the limits makes things a bit more complicated, imho. Just go from " the left" and from " the right" whenever you have points where you smell difficulties. For example, with $g(x)=|x|$ the methodology is the same as above, but the result is different! $g$ is not diff. at $0$ because from the right $g'(0)=+1$, while from the left one gets $g'(0)=-1$.

Comment: Thank you, i should have known about this website earlier :)) Thank you very much